# Sticky Table Headers & Columns - Two fixed columns

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, sticky, fixed-header-tables

I'm using the plugin [Sticky Table Headers & Columns](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/) in a table. The plugin works perfectly. My question is how to let the second column fixed. I searched the documentation and tried to contact the author, but it still fails.

I also tried adding another `<th>Sample #2</th>`, but a white block appears at the top of the column when you scrolls, as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tyanxbbs/4/).

I think I'm very close to the solution. Could anyone help me with this problem?

Solved: 
[jsfiddle.net/tyanxbbs/8](http://jsfiddle.net/tyanxbbs/8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jquery.stickyheader.js edit the below line and try.

```
$stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>'+$t.find('thead th:first-child').html()+'</th></tr></thead>');
```

to

```
$stickyInsct.html('<thead><tr><th>'+$t.find('thead th:first-child').html()+'</th><th>'+$t.find('thead th:eq(1)').html()+'</th></tr></thead>');
```

update the below line too. I just changed from 0 to 1.

```
$stickyCol.append($col)
                .find('thead th:gt(1)').remove()
                .end()
                .find('tbody td').remove();
```

Comment: I updated the code with your suggestion. But the white space still there when you scroll. I think the problem is related to the text size, take a look http://jsfiddle.net/tyanxbbs/7/

Comment: @Brightweb , I just edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well done! It works like a charm, dude. The result is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tyanxbbs/8/. Very thanks!